# Add custom .colorNames to UIColor somehow?

Tags: swift, colors, sprite-kit, uicolor

I quite like the shortcuts for using colours like this:

```
myLabel.fontColor = .gray
```

And making my own, like this:

```
static let fadedGreen = SKColor.init(hue: 0.33,
                                     saturation: 1,
                                     brightness: 0.33,
                                     alpha: 1.0)
```

But this requires calling the class I've put this in to use the abbreviation `fadedGreen` like this:

```
myLabel.fontColor = MyStorageClass.fadedGreen
```

### Question:

Is there a way I can extend or otherwise add to (what I assume are) enum presets of UIColor so I can make my own colours and just use a `.`dot like this:

```
myLabel.fontColour = .myCustomColor
```

... from anywhere in my project?

And will that mean that they're instantly available to SKColor `.presets`, too?

**Please excuse my complete ignorance of how to do something like this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't really color shortcuts. That's just inferring a type. The `fontColor` property is typed as UIColor, and UIColor has a bunch of read-only properties on the *class* that are color names and return color objects. So when you say

```
myLabel.fontColor = .myCustomColor
```

The dot tells it "it is a field somewhere, guess where" and Swift goes, well, I need a `UIColor`, so let's look if the `UIColor` class has properties of that name that return the right type.

So to add your own, you'd have to define your color properties in an extension on UIColor.

```
extension UIColor {
    static let con_pink = UIColor( red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0 )
}
```

and those you can use as `myLabel.fontColor = .con_pink`.

But note that, if you do this, you're risking collisions with any color methods Apple might add in the future. So I recommend that you add a prefix to the property names (I chose "con_" for you based on your username), to make it less likely that Apple use the same name.

Comment: I'd have preferred the unwritten "dazed" part get abbreviated to: `.dzd_pink` ;)

Comment: Note that you don't need the explicit `get { }` in the computed property. Also if this extension is only to be used by Swift code, you could mark the computed property as `@nonobjc`, thus meaning that you don't need to worry about collisions and therefore can remove the prefix.

Comment: @Hamish sorry to ask such a stupid question: where do you put the `@nonobjc` in the code?

Comment: @Confused Before the `class var`.

Comment: This is all too awesome. Thank you both! @Hamish and uliwitness. Deeply, profoundly. I think I even learnt a little about the magic of abusing the ideas of computed properties to "do" things in the way of "variables" that are really functions that are acting as variables in extensions. Or something like that.

Comment: @Hamish You're right, instead of the getter, I could also make it just a static let in the class extension's scope. Not too sure about using `@nonobjc` here (it'd go right before the static), as that only protects us from ObjC code, but could still easily cause collisions at compile-time. Also, it would make these methods unavailable to any parts of my app that have to be written in ObjC, if that is needed). So I think it mostly provides false security.

Comment: @uliwitness `static let` is indeed a good idea. I should perhaps rephrase my "don't need to worry about collisions" with `@nonobjc` – collisions can still happen, but only when two extensions of `UIColor` define a new color of the same name *and* available in the same scope. Therefore because of Swift's access modifiers, this can fairly easily be managed. But even when you do get a conflict, as you say, you'll get a compiler error. This is much more desirable than getting potentially unexpected behaviour at runtime, which is what would happen with an Obj-C naming conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply prepare a .swift file that contain all your customs constants as for example:

**Constants.swift:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// MY COLORS
let sandColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 212/255, blue: 111/255, alpha: 1)
```

Then, anywhere in your code you can do (without dot):

```
mySprite.color = sandColor
```

Obviusly you can also extend the `UIColor` as:

```
extension UIColor{
    class func fadedGreen() -> UIColor{
        return UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588 , alpha:1.00)
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let myColor = UIColor.fadedGreen()
```

Comment: is this what's known as a "global" variable?

Comment: Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any function, method, closure, or type context.Global constants and variables are always computed lazily. SAND is not a variable ("let")

Comment: Is that a yes? Or a no?

Comment: global property, I mean, then.

Comment: It's a yes but SAND is not a variable.

Comment: I've just tried this, and it fails to give me autoComplete, once I finish typing it, the colours change to show it's been recognised as a property in my project, but there's no autocomplete. Anyway I can make these shortcuts autocomplete?

Comment: Sometimes , when you write code, to work with autocomplete you should make a clean and build of the project, sometimes re-build it's enough, to enable re-indexing of terms

Comment: FAR OUT! Xcode is bug ridden, puss filled, patheticness. I don't know what [command + shift + R] does, exactly, but that worked.

Comment: An extension is far more preferable than littering the 'global' namespace with constants. Although note that to fit in with the existing colors, `fadedGreen` should be a static *property* of `UIColor`.

Comment: @Hamish can it be created, as an extension, in a manner that creates the same `.fadedGreen` style of calling with a enum looking assignment that `.gray` does?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano how do I call the function that returns the color? `UIColor.fadedGreen()` ?

Comment: @Confused Yes, like you've write.

Comment: @Hamish it's my project, I don't care about "littering the 'global' namespace". And never will. I'm a designer. If I decide a name should be in the global namespace, it has been decreed, and will be so! ;)

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I'm trying to get to `.fadedGreen`

Comment: You can't do that, because the type `UIColor` is not expressible by any literal. In other words you can't do `enum myColors : UIColor {...}`

Comment: No worries, global constants it is! `fadedGreen`, without the `.dot`, DOH!

Comment: @Confused You may not care about the global namespace, but the problem is that Apple doesn't either (they assume they own it), and authors of libraries you use may have a similarly cavalier approach. So if you don't avoid polluting the global namespace, you may get weird errors one day due to collisions. Better to stay in your own namespace, and thereby not have to deal with these issues.

Comment: @uliwitness sounds a lot like premature maintainability, to me. Something I consider a far greater sin than premature optimisation. Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't "Find and Replace" offer a fix to these problems?

Comment: I'm agree with uliwitness, you don't littering the 'global' namespace if your intentions are to made a normal project, obviusly not a public framework or library . Indeed few constants take up very little space in memory and avoid the hassle of possible collisions with future Apple framework updates or when you import libraries with UIColor extensions

Comment: @uliwitness please excuse my ignorance. What is my namespace? Is that what you did with the `con_` in the naming choice?